# Windows 10 Wi-Fi won't turn on after system boots. Putting the system to sleep and waking up works

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-10, sleep

So I just recently upgraded my system to Windows 10. Funny thing was the wireless network capabilities were disabled and I was not even able to turn on the Wi-Fi. I reinstalled again and did a lot of searching but nothing worked. I got fed up and closed my lid and after some time when I opened it back, the system just woke up from a sleep and voilà! the Wi-Fi was turned on.

Basically I upgraded to Windows 10. Wi-Fi won't turn on. Put the system to sleep and after wake up, the Wi-Fi works.

This works for me currently but I feel so dumb that I have to put my system to sleep every time I boot it up.

I am using Dell i7559, if that matters, and all my drivers are up to date.

I have already tried all the solutions suggested at https://communities.intel.com/thread/97595

How can I make my Wi-Fi work without needing this kludge?

Comment: Don't keep your drivers "up-to-date". Try installing older versions, especially if possible the ones that came with your system. These often work better.

Comment: Yeah tried rolling back my driver as well. The driver which came with system also failed.

Comment: Have you tried : (1) Deleting the WiFi in the Device Manager and reboot? (2) An offline upgrade of Windows 10 to itself (using a downloaded ISO) then redoing (1) above?

Comment: Yes. Tried deleting the wifi adapter from device manager and booted up from the iso. Still it has to go back to sleep and wake up to work again.

Comment: Try getting the wireless driver from Dell. I have only managed to find [drivers for the Inspiron 7558](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-15-7558-laptop/drivers/advanced). If nothing works, then the problem is hardware - the wifi card boots incorrectly on a cold boot, then this is fixed in a warm boot. You will then need to either (1) live with the problem, or (2) change internal adapter card (not feasible if soldered to the motherboard), or (3) use an external wifi adapter.

Comment: But it used to work fine. It stopped working only recently. Still it could be an hardware issue ?

Comment: And yeah, I was able to find the drivers for [7559](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-15-7559-laptop/drivers/advanced) as well

Comment: This seems like a relatively recent computer. If it is still under warranty, you might use it to get professional help.

Comment: Does the WiFI work when you warm reboot the laptop? As in, does it only fail on cold starts?

Comment: Is this fixed with [latest drivers](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/89450/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-3165)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem that has appeared out of nowhere.

You have tried to update all drivers, both via Windows Update and
the [Dell drivers for the Inspiron 7559](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-15-7559-laptop/drivers/advanced), but nothing worked.

I believe that as the software is up to date, this leaves only hardware.
This fits the fact that the equipment that has worked flawlessly
for quite some time suddenly stopped working correctly.

The explanation for the WiFi card to only work after waking from sleep,
would then be that the problem arrives on a cold boot,
then is fixed when the wake resets the now-warm card.

The solutions for a hardware problem are not many :

1. Live with the fact that you need to enter sleep for it to work,
   until a more serious failure will force you to take some other measure.
2. Replace the internal WiFi card (not feasible if soldered to the motherboard).
3. Use an external WiFi adapter.
4. If the computer is still under warranty, use it to get professional help.

If point 4 is still applicable, I would use it first before the warranty
elapses.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem with my pc (HP n004tx). It seems to be a problem with early versions of Windows 10. Many unofficial Windows user had similar problem.

All they had to do was 'disable' and then 'enable' the 'WiFi-Adapter' in 'Network Adapters' setting in Device manager of your system.

Comment: I tried disabling and enabling. As well as uninstalling and installing again. Without going back to sleep and waking up again, wifi doesn't want to work.